# Replacing copyright symbol python

Tags: python-3.10

I'm trying to remove copyright symbols in my dataframe. I can recognise the symbol using:

```
symbol = u'\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN}'.encode('utf-8')
symbol = symbol.decode('utf-8')
```

But when I then try to replace it, this doesn't work:

```
print(df_one.replace(symbol, ''))
```

Do I need to read the data in differently somehow? I'm currently using:

```
df_one = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob('data/*.csv')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "loc" method with the replace function:

```
df.loc[:, "column_name"].replace({character},regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't remove the symbol from my data though

Answer (score 1):

averroes response almost worked. This is the solution I now have that does work:

```
df.loc[:, "column_name"].replace({symbol: ' '},regex=True)
```